# nl2br puts br between html tags

Tags: php

I have a PHP webmail script that I received today message from gmail like this:

```
$content='
<p>This is just example for MessageContent</
p>Test...<span>Test</span>Test..<span
>Test</span>';
```

How can I print it with `nl2br`?

If I use `echo nl2br($content);`, I get this result:

```
<br />
<p>This is just example for MessageContent</<br />
p>Test...<span>Test</span>Test..<span<br />
>Test</span>
```

So how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Instead of trying to format text with nl2br, wouldn't it be better to put it in a containing element and style that to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Why do you want this to begin with? You should only apply `nl2br` on text that isn't already HTML.

Comment: You should manually fix that html code, those broken-in-the-heart tags are unhealthy.

Comment: If it contain HTML already, just output as-is

Comment: Uhm, so you're complaining that nl2br() is adding a br 2 a nl? it must surely be a bug! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think accepting html in a message is bad, and you should strip out any html, why?

Because if you accept html tobe rendered. eg: not using `htmlentities($content)` from an unknown source then a malicious person could add
javascript and [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) attack you, or a dodgy link and [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) you or even just a 1px image and get your IP.

But if you accept the risk you can just render the message as-is.

```
<?php 
$content='
<p>This is just example for MessageContent</
p>Test...<span>Test</span>Test..<span
>Test</span>';

//Or at least sanitise abit - Remove all tags except p's an a's
$content = strip_tags($content,'<p><a>');
?>
```

nl2br is for content you expect to have no html in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could either change $content to

```
$content='
<p>This is just example for MessageContent</p>
Test...<span>Test</span>Test..
<span>Test</span>';
```

Or you could just use

```
echo $content;
```